# How to disable babel block indentation?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, indentation

Is it possible to disable the indentation of new babel source blocks?

I played with `electric-indent-local-mode` and `org-src-preserve-indentation` without success.

Current output:

```
* aa
** bb
   #+begin_src shell

   #+end_src
```

Expected output:

```
* aa
** bb
#+begin_src shell

#+end_src
```

Comment: Does this happen only with source blocks or with regular text as well? If the latter, it seems the case of disabling `org-indent-mode` (`M-x org-indent-mode`).

Comment: Did you try `(setq org-adapt-indentation nil)`?